# How do I make search based on some property in JSON in Notes View

Tags: json, lotus-notes, lotusscript, notesview

Suppose I have a NotesDocument with a property named `"someJSONObject"` with the following value:

```
"{
 "someObject": 
  {
   "objId": "someId"
   "Object_Name": "objName",
   "Alternative_Name" : "altName",
   "Alias_Name" : "alias"
  }
}"
```

My question is how I can get `"objId"` property to use it in Notes View in such a way, so I would be able to use this as a seach criteria. There are only "Simple Function", "Field", "Formula" available. How can I write it there, instead of writing duplicate field just for sorting purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lines to do it with formula: First split the values into an array with @Explode, then find the line / lines with "objID" and get the values from them. This code even works, if there are multiple objID- Tags in JSON.

```
_allVals := @Explode( someJSONObject; @Newline );
REM "Depending of the origin of your data, you need to replace @NewlIne by @Char( 10 ) , @Char( 13 ) or a combination of them";

_objIDString := @Trim( @Right( _allVals ) ; {"objId": } ) );
_objID := @LeftBack( @Right( _objIDString ; {"} ) ; {"} );
_objID
```

Just one remark: After saving the curly brackets will be replaced by " and all " inside them will be masked with "\".

This code: `@Right( _objIDString ; {"} )` will then look like this `@Right( _objIDString ; "\"" )`

This is done for downwards compatibility as older versions of notes don't understand the curly brackets.

Comment: Don't you know how to get every "expertID" here? Inside allExperts array? 

{
 "allAssignedExperts" : 
 {
  "assignmentDate" : "someDateHere",
  "allExperts" : 
  [
   {
    "expertId" : "someId",
    "expertNameSurname" : "someNameHere",
    "didExceedDeadline" : "false",
    "isLead" : "false"
   },
   {
    "expertId" : "anotherId",
    "expertNameSurname" : "anotherNameHere",
    "didExceedDeadline" : "true",
    "isLead" : "true"
   }
  ]
 }
}
Please use this service to make it look pretty 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: And what if my json object doesn't have newLine separation?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using [JSON LotusScript Classes](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/JSON%20LotusScript%20Classes) in your [project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49359123/2065611).

Create a LotusScript agent which

- runs on all your documents with the JSON field and
- extracts the needed values with the help of JSON LotusScript Classes and
- puts them in separate document's fields
- which can be used in view's columns

In case you write the JSON field with some LotusScript code already you could add the field separation right there.